# Sheets Formula: Duplicates in Column A with different content in column B

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet like this:

Name1 Job1

Name1 Job2

Name2 Job3

Name2 Job4

Name3 Job5

Name3 Job20

And I need a formula to get the first unique entry based on Column A.

The result should look like:

Name1 Job1

Name2 Job3

Name3 Job5

Can anyone help me out?

I tried unique/query combinations without the expected result

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try getting the UNIQUE values from Column A, and then using VLOOKUP (or XLOOKUP):

```
=LET(names,UNIQUE(A2:A),
{names,ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(names,A2:B,2,0))})
```